# DAO, SERVICE layer what for

Tags: spring, service, architecture, dao, layer

What for this two layers? Why we must execute dao-method in service? Why we should use @Transactional only in Service method fields. Why we can't use @Transactional on the dao methods directly and don't use the services?

Comment: `@Transactional` is used in service layer so multiple dao methods can be done in single transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

beacuase there is many ways to manage the transactions called transaction Propagation

TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_MANDATORY : Supports a current transaction; throws an exception if no current transaction exists.

TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_NESTED : Executes within a nested transaction if a current transaction exists.

TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_NEVER : Does not support a current transaction; throws an exception if a current transaction exists.

TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_NOT_SUPPORTED : Does not support a current transaction; rather always execute nontransactionally.

TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRED : Supports a current transaction; creates a new one if none exists.

TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW : Creates a new transaction, suspending the current transaction if one exists.

TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS : Supports a current transaction; executes non-transactionally if none exists.

TransactionDefinition.TIMEOUT_DEFAULT : Uses the default timeout of the underlying transaction system, or none if timeouts are not supported.